# AngularJS v1.3.8 Causes "Aw, Snap" in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I have an Angular App that we recently upgraded to AngularJS v1.3.8 and now we get intermittent "Aw, Snap" crashes in chrome. But the app runs fine in other browsers and on certain computers.

Any time we encounter this error a refresh fixes it immediately.

We have explored many options trying to figure out the root cause of this issue:
   - Verify memory profile
   - Verify CPU profile
   - Verify Hardware Acceleration on/off 
   - Verify minified/unminified AngularJSv1.3.8

When we reverted back to Angular v1.2.7 we no longer see this crash.  We have isolated this change and is the ONLY change between revisions.

Has  anyone experienced this as well? Or does anyone know of any reasons for this? Or any compatibility issues that could lead to this error?

Error encountered using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)

Comment: It'd be pretty hard to pull the reason out of thin air. There are a lot of changes between the two I suggest reading the changelog of all the versions: github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. Beyond that start ripping your app apart and try to see what eventually passes. Do you have automated testing set up?

Comment: We've looked through the changelog and have applied fixes for all breaking changes as proven through working in other browsers (and inconsistently on chrome).  We do have automated testing, and we've tried 'ripping the app apart', but it's a large codebase and we aren't convinced its in our code since a refresh fixes the issue.

Comment: I don't suppose you have ever figured this out? We are running in to a very similiar (if not exactly the same) issue.

Comment: We are hitting the same thing with angular 1.3.11. No clue on how to fix it.

Comment: I have this same problem. Even the Angular Material demo website crashes

Answer (score 0):

For us, this occurred when we did an $injector.invoke inside a responseError interceptor. It seems that it is sensitive to that.

Comment: 1.3.14 does not appear to have this issue.